# What is the 2007 Microsoft Office Plugin for Netscape Navigator?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-office-2007

After installing Office 2007, the following plugin shows up in Firefox:

> **2007 Microsoft Office system**   12.0.4518.1014
>   Office Plugin for Netscape Navigator

What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nobody knows.**

1. Google doesn't know. There is a pretty good article about the previous version on [ProcessList](http://processlist.com/info/npoffice.html).

   But the current version? No details. This page is #5 on the results!
2. Microsoft doesn't know. Use the inline "Bing" interface at www.microsoft.com

At some point in the future, I would expect the Mozilla Plugin Checker will at least display the current version, but I think that is all you can determine for now, without calling Microsoft and getting the paid-for-support answer.

Answer (score 2):

That plugin should allow you to open Microsoft Office documents in Firefox (when you click on a link), rather than having to download the file and then open the file in the proper program.

Comment: Under which circumstances does that happen? I activated the plugin and tried it... it just doesn't do what you describe, I always get the download dialog -- even if the server does everything correctly (Content-Type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" and no "Content-Disposition: attachment").

Comment: @Heinzi: just a hint: go to `about:plugins` page in Firefox and you can see the MIME types the plugin is supposed to handle.

Comment: @Amro: Thanks, good idea. Apparently, this plugin only handles `application/x-msoffice12`. No idea what kind of file that would be...

Answer (score 2):

This plugin should allow you to view, alter, and save excel workbooks online (such as spreadsheets hosted on docs.google.com)